# OSX: Don't login as network user, but as local

Tags: mac-osx, authentication, login, apple

Normally my computer was set up to login as a network user, but it also has a local home set up.  I have moved my computer to a new location where that server no longer is, so there is no longer a network home.  Now, when I try to login to my computer, it does not take my password.  It seems like it is searching for my network user account or something, and it never find the password.

How can I force it to use the local account of the same username, and not look for the network account?

Comment: Is this a second account with the same name as the network account, or are you trying to logon to a cached logon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the network server from the LDAP search path in directory utility.

That said you will always authenticate against your local directory before the network, that is to say if you had an account on the computer and on the network with the same name, you will always logon to the local account.  Hence you have other problems.